# Cannot zoom map after changing camera position in Google Maps v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

After starting new project, i've faced a problem with zooming maps in google maps v2 in android. I can't zoom map using default controls. The following code shows Camera position changing

```
    CameraPosition currentPlace = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(mMarker.getPosition())
                    .bearing(bearing) 
                    .zoom(14f) //apply zoom here
                    .build();
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(currentPlace));
```

After this function i cannot zoom map with default controls

[image: Controls are not working]

Comment: are you sure, the `moveCamera()` is the problem? it's working for me pretty well. even if i use your code.

Comment: could you please show us the xml layout of this activity?

Comment: Are you sure your not at max zoom?  Not all areas have tiles at the largest zoom level currently 21.

Comment: All what you need you have to [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views) and they use not "moveCamera" but "animateCamera" (bottom of articles)

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is that we should use markers zoom when we move camera :

```
CameraPosition currentPlace = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(mMarker.getPosition()).bearing(bearing)
                .zoom(map.getCameraPosition().zoom) 
                .build();
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(currentPlace));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
**get the location longitude  and latitude**

```
  static LatLng loc1 = new LatLng(6.9009960, 79.8548823);
  //zoom the location
  map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(loc1, 15));
```

Comment: Yes, but i need to apply bearing to camera, to change markers angle according to compass